# Virtual method not called

Tags: c++, googletest

I am writing a class, `BTree`, to implement a binary tree in C++ and I am using Google Test to test it.  I have created a virtual method, `visit()`, to the base class which prints out the data from the current node every time it's called.

By visual inspection I can see that the numbers are output in the correct order.  However, I want to be able to test this automatically with Google Test.  In order to do this, I have created a subclass, `InOrderTest`, which overrides the `visit()` method so that it appends to a string instead of printing it out.  However, the base class version is being called instead of the sub-class.  What am I doing wrong?

This is the test case:

```
TEST_F(BTreeTestSuite, inOrder)
{
    class InOrderTest : public BTree
    {
    public:
        InOrderTest(int data) throw(int) : BTree(data), itsVisitString() {};
        std::string visitString(void) const { return itsVisitString; }
        virtual void visit()
        {
            std::ostringstream oss;
            oss << itsData;
            itsVisitString += oss.str();
            std::cerr << "vs1: " << itsVisitString << '|' << std::endl;
            itsVisitString += " ";
            std::cerr << "vs2: " << itsVisitString << '|' << std::endl;
        }
    private:
        std::string itsVisitString;
    };
    InOrderTest iot(20);
    iot.insert(30);
    iot.insert(15);
    iot.insert(10);
    iot.inOrder();
    EXPECT_STREQ("10 15 20 30 ", iot.visitString().c_str());
}
```

And this is the (hopefully) relevant portions of the base class:

```
class BTree
{
public:
    BTree(int data) throw();    // constructor(s)
    ~BTree() throw();       // destructor

    void insert(int data);
    unsigned count() const;
    void inOrder() const;

    int   data() const throw() { return itsData; };
    BTree *left() const throw() { return itsLeft; };
    BTree *right() const throw() { return itsRight; };
protected:
    virtual void visit() const;
    int itsData;
private:
    // Don't allow creation of BTree without data
    BTree() throw();    // constructor(s)
    BTree   *itsLeft;
    BTree   *itsRight;
protected:
};
...
void BTree::inOrder() const
{
    if (itsLeft) itsLeft->inOrder();
    visit();
    if (itsRight) itsRight->inOrder();
}

void BTree::visit() const
{
    cout << itsData << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not including the `const`. That changes the signature of the function and it ends up hiding the one in the base class instead of overriding it. It's a good idea, for this reason, to append `override` when overriding a function because then you'll get a compiler error when it doesn't override anything (C++11 only on that one, though). Change it to:

```
virtual void visit() const /*override*/ {
//^^optional, especially with the override
```

Comment: Arggh!  That was it!  At least it only took 2 minutes to get an answer.

Comment: Now I have another problem.  The insert code is only in the base class so only the first node is the sub-class.  All the rest are the base-class so the `visit()` method is only called once from the subclass.  I don't really understand how to fix this.  The `insert()` method logic works except it needs to insert a derived class instead of the base class and I don't know how to do this.  I could make the `insert()` method virtual and override it but I don't want to replicate all the logic again in the subclass.

Comment: @StephenRasku, That would probably be better as a separate question.

Comment: New question is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727037/base-method-called-in-google-test