# Base method called in Google Test

Tags: c++, googletest

I am trying to write a binary tree implementation in C++ and I'm testing it using Google Test.  In order to test the in-order traversal I am sub-classing the `BTree` class so that I can override the `visit()` method so that I can output to a string instead of to the console.  The problem is that I want to use the existing logic to insert new nodes to the tree and it's inserting the base class instead of the derived class even though I am passing a pointer to a derived object to the `insert()` method.  Is there a way to get it to insert the derived class for all the nodes?

Here's the test case:

```
TEST_F(BTreeTestSuite, inOrder)
{
    class InOrderTest : public BTree
    {
    public:
        InOrderTest(int data) throw(int) : BTree(data), itsVisitString() {};
        virtual ~InOrderTest() {};
        std::string visitString(void) const { return itsVisitString; }
        virtual void visit()
        {
            std::ostringstream oss;
            oss << itsData;
            itsVisitString += oss.str();
            std::cerr << "vs1: " << itsVisitString << '|' << std::endl;
            itsVisitString += " ";
            std::cerr << "vs2: " << itsVisitString << '|' << std::endl;
        }
    private:
        std::string itsVisitString;
    };
    InOrderTest iot(20);
    iot.insert(new InOrderTest(30));
    iot.insert(new InOrderTest(15));
    iot.insert(new InOrderTest(10));
    iot.inOrder();
    EXPECT_STREQ("10 15 20 30 ", iot.visitString().c_str());
}
```

Here's the relevant portions of the base class:

```
class BTree
{
public:
    BTree(int data) throw();        // constructor(s)
    ~BTree() throw();               // destructor

    virtual void insert(BTree *node);
    unsigned count() const;
    void inOrder();
    virtual void visit();

    int   data() const throw() { return itsData; };
    BTree *left() const throw() { return itsLeft; };
    BTree *right() const throw() { return itsRight; };

protected:
    int     itsData;
private:
    // Don't allow creation of BTree without data
    BTree() throw();        // constructor(s)
    BTree   *itsLeft;
    BTree   *itsRight;
};
...
BTree::BTree(int data) throw() : itsData(data)
{
    itsLeft = itsRight = 0;
}

void BTree::insert(BTree *node)
{
    if (node->itsData < itsData)
    {
        std::cerr << "Inserting data on the left\n";
        if (itsLeft)
        {
            itsLeft->insert(node);
        }
        else
        {
            itsLeft = new BTree(node->itsData);
        }

    }

    if (node->itsData > itsData)
    {
        std::cerr << "Inserting data on the right\n";
        if (itsRight)
        {
            itsRight->insert(node);
        }
        else
        {
            itsRight = new BTree(node->itsData);
        }
    }

    /* Drop value if it already exists in tree. */
}

void BTree::inOrder()
{
    if (itsLeft) itsLeft->inOrder();
    visit();
    if (itsRight) itsRight->inOrder();
}

void BTree::visit()
{
    cout << "base-visit: " << itsData << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `BTree::insert` method. Even though it's getting a `InOrderTest *` you're creating an instance of `BTree` from that on these two lines:

```
void BTree::insert(BTree *node)
{
  // logic checks...
  itsLeft = new BTree(node->itsData);
  // more logic checks...
  itsRight = new BTree(node->itsData);
  //...
}
```

There are two approaches you can take to solve this. You can just use the node passed in instead of constructing a new object. In this case, your root node assumes ownership of its children and should take care of deallocating them as appropriate. Since your unittest is doing `new InOrderTest` with no matching `delete` anyway, this approach can work.

The second way is to create a virtual `clone` method and have your derive classes handle its own creation of itself.

```
class BTree
{
  // BTree stuff
public:
  virtual BTree* BTree::clone() const;
  // more stuff
};

class InOrderTest : public BTree
{
public:
  InOrderTest* clone() const { return new InOrderTest(*this); }
};
```

Also, if you expect client code using `BTree` to derive from it then make `BTree::~BTree` destructor virtual. (See Effective C++ item#7)

Comment: I changed it to use the node passed in instead of creating a new node.  It was a silly oversight.